# Pandas groupby all rows between boolean column values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Looking for the Pandas syntax for grouping rows between column boolean values.

##### DataTable

| distance | time | new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-10-11 1:30:15 | true |
| 5 | 2020-10-11 1:31:15 | false |
| 10 | 2020-10-11 1:32:15 | false |
| 1 | 2020-10-11 2:30:15 | true |
| 2 | 2020-10-11 2:31:15 | false |
| 30 | 2020-10-11 2:32:15 | false |
| 31 | 2020-10-11 2:33:15 | false |
| 0 | 2020-10-12 1:31:15 | true |
| 5 | 2020-10-12 1:32:15 | false |

##### Question

Looking to group all the rows that are a part of each activity. A new activity is determined by the true value in the new column. Based on the data above there should be 3 groups. Each group needs to start with the first row with True and end with the last False before the next True.
How can this be achieved using `groupby`?

##### Code

Here is the ability to use `groupby` and group by the date, but like I said above, I'm looking to change this to group by the "new" column group rows into activities. I'm planning to use in a for loop like this though.

```
for idx, day in df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.date):
    print(idx)
    print(day)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by `df['new'].cumsum()`:

```py
for idx, day in df.groupby(df['new'].cumsum()):
    print('-----')
    print(idx)
    print(day)
```

Output:

```
-----
1
   distance                time    new
0         0  2020-10-11+1:30:15   True
1         5  2020-10-11+1:31:15  False
2        10  2020-10-11+1:32:15  False
-----
2
   distance                time    new
3         1  2020-10-11+2:30:15   True
4         2  2020-10-11+2:31:15  False
5        30  2020-10-11+2:32:15  False
6        31  2020-10-11+2:33:15  False
-----
3
   distance                time    new
7         0  2020-10-12+1:31:15   True
8         5  2020-10-12+1:32:15  False
```

Comment: That was it. I figured that there had to be an easy method to do this in pandas. Thanks!